# How do I open a Word 2013 document in a WebBrowser control on a C# Winform?

Tags: c#, office-automation

In my C# Winforms application, I have a WebBrowser control in which I want to show a Word document.  I display the document by calling
`webBrowser1.Navigate(myDocName)`.

This works fine for documents through Word 2003.

For Word 2007 and 2010, this caused Word to open the document in a newly created instance of Word, not on the Winform containing the WebBrowser.  I was able to fix this by adding the following registry entries on the client machine (note that this can be done for Excel as well - the value to write is `(int)0x80000A00`, and the classes are `\Excel.Sheet` in place of `\Word.Document`):

```
int wordFlagValue = (int)0x80000024;

Common.SaveToRegistryLocalMachine(@"SOFTWARE\Classes\Word.Document.8", "BrowserFlags", wordFlagValue);

Common.SaveToRegistryLocalMachine(@"SOFTWARE\Classes\Word.Document.12", "BrowserFlags", wordFlagValue);
```

Note: `Common.SaveToRegistryLocalMachine()` is simply a wrapper function to write a registry entry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

The problem is that some clients now have Word 2013 installed, and the new Word instance problem appeared again.  I tried adding the following registry entries (to reflect the new versions of Word), but to no effect:

```
Common.SaveToRegistryLocalMachine(@"SOFTWARE\Classes\Word.Document.14", "BrowserFlags", wordFlagValue);
Common.SaveToRegistryLocalMachine(@"SOFTWARE\Classes\Word.Document.15", "BrowserFlags", wordFlagValue);
```

Any ideas on how to work around this problem?

Comment: There is no Word 2005 or Word 2008.

Comment: If I had to solve this, I would use something like [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx) (costs certain amount of money!) to render the Word document to images and display the images in a picture box control or similar.

Comment: @UweKeim yup, I use Aspose.Words for my own projects and I've found it to be a very capable system, if expensive.

Comment: @Dai There is also [Spire.Doc](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/word-viewer-net-introduce.html#.VO5Ibqi5ZBc) with similar functionality and probably a few bucks less, altough I've never tried myself so I don't know the quality of their Word renderer.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Just hosting Word in a form?

Comment: > Just hosting Word in a form? - yes

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: While I work for Microsoft and on Internet Explorer, I have no special knowledge in this area)

I believe the problem is because Office 2013 no-longer supports being hosted by Internet Explorer[citation needed!]. This is for a variety of reasons, but I think because the vision we (as a company) held for OLE and COM never really worked-out and it generally presents a poor user-experience (remember trying to edit an embedded Excel spreadsheet in a Word document after resizing it?).

I remember that Office 2003 did support being hosted by other processes (such as Internet Explorer and even Visual Studio 6.0) but since Office 2007 I believe they disabled that functionality by default and you had to jump through hoops to get it to work, and then they disabled it completely in 2013. **I think**, do not take this as authoritative information!

If I'm wrong (which I very well might be) the problem might be because you have a 64-bit process (e.g. `AnyCPU` in .NET on an x64 OS) but the 32-bit version of Office installed, you cannot mix 32-bit and 64-bit binaries in the same process, so it's possible that it would work, but fails in this because because it's the wrong ISA.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I hope MS realizes this really puts developers in a bad spot.  They give us an easy way to deliver cool functionality to our users, then they break it when the user updates.  Now the user expects functionality that MS has prevented us from using for no good reason.

Comment: @qwerty13579 I sympathize, however I disagree that the change was done "for no good reason" - I've already cited usability and platform concerns as the basis for such a decision. It is the responsibility of developers and system-integrators to test new versions of software (such as Office) before deploying them to identify issues like these (and develop alternative solutions for them) before users do.

Comment: Dai - as a developer, I have no control over when a user updates his version of Office, then his software stops working.  A core tenant of compatibility is not taking away functionality, and for what this functionality was typically used for (simply displaying an Office doc to a user) there were no usability problems